# Why can't it find my BasicAuthenticationModule?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, basic-authentication

I'm trying to create my own implementation of a basic-authentication.

I have `BasicAuthenticationModule.cs` stored in my `solution\Modules` and its namespace is:

```
namespace Web_API.Modules
{
public class BasicAuthenticationModule2 : IHttpModule
```

Ive added it to my web.config as such:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="BasicAuthenticationModule" type="Web_API.Modules.BasicAuthenticationModule, BasicAuthenticationModule"/>
```

Running this gets me: `HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error - Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'BasicAuthenticationModule'`

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: BasicAuthenticationModule2 ?

Comment: I now get 'Could not load file or assembly 'BasicAuthenticationModule' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Comment: Wouldn't the type be `Web_API.Modules.BasicAuthenticationModule2`?

Comment: Its seems rubbish, but i renamed my class to 'BasicAuthenticationModule2'. My 'system.WebServer' 'modules' now looks like: '<add name="BasicAuthHttpModule" type="Web_API.Modules.BasicAuthenticationModule2, BasicAuthenticationModule2" />' im still getting: 'Could not load file or assembly 'BasicAuthenticationModule2' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Comment: Try just `<add name="BasicAuthenticationModule2" type=" Web_API.Modules.BasicAuthenticationModule2"/>`

Comment: Go back to your first approach and add <clear/> just after the <modules> element, that would take care of the duplicate entry problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because there already is a built-in module called **`BasicAuthorizationModule`** that comes inside .NET.

You would need to either:

- use a different `Name` *(e.g. `BasicAuthModule`)*
- remove the existing `BasicAuthorizationModeule` module entry