# Why will it not find my module?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, basic-authentication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can’t it find my BasicAuthenticationModule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667055/why-cant-it-find-my-basicauthenticationmodule)

I'm trying to create my own implementation of a basic-authentication.

I have `BasicAuthenticationModule.cs` stored in my `solution\Modules` and its namespace is:

```
namespace Web_API.Modules
{
    public class BasicAuthenticationModule : IHttpModule
```

Ive added it to my web.config as such:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="MyBasicAuthenticationModule" type="Web_API.Modules.BasicAuthenticationModule, BasicAuthenticationModule" />
```

I get the following error when running this:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not load file or assembly 'BasicAuthenticationModule' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'BasicAuthenticationModule' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How is your assembly named on disk that holds your class?

Comment: @rene Could you please specify?

Comment: The project that holds your class has an output filename as it is compiled in a dll. I suspect the name of the dll is not BasicAuthenticationModule but maybe Web_API or something like that.

Comment: Why are you following a ASP.NET 2.0 tutorial for your MVC4 project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have specified wrong assembly name for your module. When you write:

```
type="Web_API.Modules.BasicAuthenticationModule, BasicAuthenticationModule"
```

this means to load a class called `BasicAuthenticationModule` inside an `Web_API.Modules` namespace within an assembly called `BasicAuthenticationModule`. Is the project in which you defined this class called `BasicAuthenticationModule`? I guess not. That's why ASP.NET cannot load your module. You should specify the correct assembly name in which this module is defined.

For example if your ASP.NET MVC application is called `MvcAPplication1` the definition might look like this:

```
type="Web_API.Modules.BasicAuthenticationModule, MvcApplication1"
```

The format of the type attribute is like this:

```
type="Namespace.ClassName, AssemblyName"
```

Comment: Now im getting 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: typeName' on the following in my module: 'string provider = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Web_API.Modules.BasicAuthenticationModule.AuthProvider"];
            Type providerType = Type.GetType(provider, true);'

provider is null, do I have to define it somewhere?

Comment: Well, you seem to have defined some `Web_API.Modules.BasicAuthenticationModule.Auth‌​Provider` setting in your web.config file which is pointing to some runtime type. Make sure that it also follows the `"Namespace.ClassName, AssemblyName"` pattern and that this type actually exists. It's hard to tell but at least now your module is loaded and executed which was your original question.

Comment: I took a wild guess and it works...

Comment: @DarinDimitrov could he also have just done `<add name="MyBasicAuthenticationModule" type="Web_API.Modules.BasicAuthenticationModule" />`?